# Link to unique row and filter accordingly with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button, filter, hyperlink

I am trying to create a macro enabled button or hyperlink that once clicked will link to a value in the same row, copy its value and go to another sheet and apply a filter based on that value.

edit: Here is the Hyperlink formula I used.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!d6","Press button to filter")
```

Sub Macro2()
'

```
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R6C4"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-33, 3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$R$206909").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "copy this value"
End Sub
```

This is the Macro I tried using but can't get the hyperlink to use the macro and it doesn't work when I try to use it on a different row.

macro enabled button
[image: macro enabled button]

takes the value and puts in a filter
[image: takes the value and puts in a filter]

Comment: Pretty pictures. Please [edit] your question to include the code you've written.

Comment: Instead of multiple buttons I recommend to use only one button (eg in the header) that copies the value from the selected row. I think this is easier to accomplish. Also using the *Macro Recorder* might help to get an idea of the code.

Comment: PEH, that is a great idea, do you happen to have any guide that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one button only. Eg. put a button into your header and link it to the following procedure.

```
Public Sub FilterByRowValue()
    Dim FilterValue As Variant

    If Selection.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        FilterValue = Selection.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select 1 row only."
    End If

    'filter whatever you want here.
    Worksheets("SheetName").Range("$A$3:$R$206909").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=FilterValue
End Sub
```

So you just need to select any cell in the desired row and click the button. It takes the value of column E of your selection and filters for it.

Adjust the code to your needs.